# Stop text labels from overlapping in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, stringr

So I have a dataframe like so

```
df <- structure(list(Reportable = c("A", "B", 
                                  "A", "B", "A", 
                                  "B", "A", "B", 
                                  "A", "B", "A", 
                                  "B", "A", "B"
), Location1_Description = c("MAIN/BRANCH", "MAIN/BRANCH", "YARD", 
                             "YARD", "PART", "PART", "SHOP", 
                             "SHOP", "LOT", "LOT", "HIGHWAY/ROADWAY", 
                             "HIGHWAY/ROADWAY", "OFFICE", "OFFICE"
), count = c(146L, 447L, 83L, 241L, 44L, 89L, 38L, 83L, 16L, 
             28L, 4L, 30L, 11L, 21L), pct = c("25%", "75%", "26%", "74%", 
                                              "33%", "67%", "31%", "69%", "36%", "64%", "12%", "88%", "33%", 
                                              "64%"), total = c("146 (25%)", "447 (75%)", "83 (26%)", "241 (74%)", 
                                                                "44 (33%)", "89 (67%)", "38 (31%)", "83 (69%)", "16 (36%)", "28 (64%)", 
                                                                "4 (12%)", "30 (88%)", "11 (33%)", "21 (64%)"), total1 = c("146\n(25%)", 
                                                                                                                           "447\n(75%)", "83\n(26%)", "241\n(74%)", "44\n(33%)", "89\n(67%)", 
                                                                                                                           "38\n(31%)", "83\n(69%)", "16\n(36%)", "28\n(64%)", "4\n(12%)", 
                                                                                                                           "30\n(88%)", "11\n(33%)", "21\n(64%)")), row.names = c(NA, -14L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

And I plot as such

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)
library(ggthemes)
ggplot(df, aes(fill=Reportable, y=count, x=as.factor(Location1_Description), label = total)) +
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity")+
  aes(stringr::str_wrap(as.factor(Location1_Description), 15), count) +
  labs(x = "", y = "Injury Count", fill = "")+
 geom_text(size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("darkorange", "cornflowerblue") ) +
  theme_hc() +
  coord_flip()
```

If you notice, the labels keep overlapping eachother within the plot. I've tried some size changes but I can't get it to look legible. How could I make it clear what each mini bar is saying???

My end result should be a plot which I can see clearly what count/pct (`total`) is for each bar.

Comment: @aosmith it's not axis labels, rather the labels on the plot itself

Comment: The dataframe code is broken. It ends on `, row.names = c(NA, -14L`. Please fix it. I can't run your code, but have you tried to use the `ggrepel` package?

Comment: @DanielR Apoligies, fixed

Answer (score 3):

Another option is using the [`ggfittext`](https://github.com/wilkox/ggfittext) package.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)
library(ggthemes)

df <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  Reportable = c("A","B","A","B","A","B","A","B",
                 "A","B","A","B","A","B"),
  Location1_Description = c("MAIN/BRANCH","MAIN/BRANCH","YARD",
                            "YARD","PART","PART","SHOP","SHOP",
                            "LOT","LOT","HIGHWAY/ROADWAY",
                            "HIGHWAY/ROADWAY","OFFICE","OFFICE"),
  count = c(146L,447L,83L,241L,44L,89L,38L,
            83L,16L,28L,4L,30L,11L,21L),
  pct = c("25%","75%","26%","74%","33%","67%",
          "31%","69%","36%","64%","12%",
          "88%","33%","64%"),
  total = c("146 (25%)","447 (75%)","83 (26%)",
            "241 (74%)","44 (33%)","89 (67%)",
            "38 (31%)","83 (69%)","16 (36%)","28 (64%)",
            "4 (12%)","30 (88%)","11 (33%)",
            "21 (64%)"),
  total1 = c("146\n(25%)","447\n(75%)","83\n(26%)",
             "241\n(74%)","44\n(33%)","89\n(67%)",
             "38\n(31%)","83\n(69%)","16\n(36%)",
             "28\n(64%)","4\n(12%)","30\n(88%)",
             "11\n(33%)","21\n(64%)")
)

p <- ggplot(df, aes(fill = Reportable, y = count, x = as.factor(Location1_Description), label = total)) +
  geom_bar(position = "stack", stat = "identity") +
  aes(stringr::str_wrap(as.factor(Location1_Description), 15), count) +
  labs(x = "", y = "Injury Count", fill = "") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("darkorange", "cornflowerblue")) +
  theme_hc() +
  coord_flip()

library(ggfittext)
p +
  geom_bar_text(position = "stack", 
                outside = TRUE,
                min.size = 2,
                reflow = TRUE)
```

[image]

```r
p +
  geom_bar_text(position = "stack", 
                outside = TRUE,
                grow = FALSE,
                min.size = 2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You already have a `position_stack` on the text labels, so you will have to manually `position_dodge` them too:

```r
ggplot(Location1_counts, aes(fill = Reportable, y = count, 
                             x = as.factor(Location1_Description), 
                             label = total)) +
  geom_bar(position = "stack", stat = "identity") +
  aes(stringr::str_wrap(as.factor(Location1_Description), 15), count) +
  labs(x = "", y = "Injury Count", fill = "") +
  geom_text(data = Location1_counts %>% 
                   mutate(total = ifelse(Reportable == "B", "", total)),
            size = 3, vjust = 2, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  geom_text(data = Location1_counts %>% 
                   mutate(total = ifelse(Reportable == "A", "", total)),
            size = 3, vjust = -1.5, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("darkorange", "cornflowerblue") ) +
  theme_hc() +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>